# Merging arrays of versioned dictionaries

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, merge

Given the following two arrays of dictionaries, how can I *merge* them such that the resulting array of dictionaries contains only those dictionaries whose *version* is greatest?

```
data1 = [{'id': 1, 'name': u'Oneeee', 'version': 2},
         {'id': 2, 'name': u'Two', 'version': 1},
         {'id': 3, 'name': u'Three', 'version': 2},
         {'id': 4, 'name': u'Four', 'version': 1},
         {'id': 5, 'name': u'Five', 'version': 1}]

data2 = [{'id': 1, 'name': u'One', 'version': 1},
         {'id': 2, 'name': u'Two', 'version': 1},
         {'id': 3, 'name': u'Threeee', 'version': 3},
         {'id': 6, 'name': u'Six', 'version': 2}]
```

The *merged* result should look like this:

```
data3 = [{'id': 1, 'name': u'Oneeee', 'version': 2},
         {'id': 2, 'name': u'Two', 'version': 1},
         {'id': 3, 'name': u'Threeee', 'version': 3},
         {'id': 4, 'name': u'Four', 'version': 1},
         {'id': 5, 'name': u'Five', 'version': 1},
         {'id': 6, 'name': u'Six', 'version': 2}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the highest version according to the dictionaries `id`s then you can use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.groupby) method like this:

```
sdata = sorted(data1 + data2, key=lambda x:x['id'])
res = []
for _,v in itertools.groupby(sdata, key=lambda x:x['id']):
    v = list(v)
    if len(v) > 1:    # happened that the same id was in both datas
        # append the one with higher version
        res.append(v[0] if v[0]['version'] > v[1]['version'] else v[1])
    else:             # the id was in one of the two data
        res.append(v[0])
```

The solution is not a one liner but I think is simple enough (once you understand `groupby()` which is not trivial).

This will result in `res` containing this list:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': u'Oneeee', 'version': 2},
 {'id': 2, 'name': u'Two', 'version': 1},
 {'id': 3, 'name': u'Threeee', 'version': 3},
 {'id': 4, 'name': u'Four', 'version': 1},
 {'id': 5, 'name': u'Five', 'version': 1},
 {'id': 6, 'name': u'Six', 'version': 2}]
```

I think is possible to *shrink* the solution even more, but it could be quite hard to understand.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes! That works great. I just don't understand how `zip()` works here.

Comment: `zip()` takes a variable number of iterables and return and iterable of tuples of objects in the same index in the iterables.

Comment: Before trying the solution, test `zip` on simple lists and in your proper input data to take a grasp of how it work :)

Comment: `zip()` generates a list of tuples. Each tuple, in this case, is a tuple of (`data1[i], data2[i])` where `i` is the i'th index for each list.

Comment: I get it. It's just operating on ordered pairs of dictionaries in each array. What if the arrays were of different lengths?

Comment: If the array where of different lengths then you can use `itertools` and `izip_longest` for example: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.izip_longest

Comment: Okay, I updated my example to be a little less trivial.

Comment: @MarkRichman in that case It seems you don't just want to filter according to `version`. Somehow `name` play a role also, otherwise why `Six` is the last one?

Comment: @PauloBu the names are irrelevant. I just need a merged list, where the record with greatest version is kept.

Comment: @MarkRichman in that case take a look at the example again, from my point of view, last to row would be: `{'id': 4, 'name': u'Six', 'version': 2}, {'id': 5, 'name': u'Five', 'version': 1}`. Six is in the same indext as Four and has higher version, am I right?

Comment: you probably also need to make sure you are comparing versions of the same id.

Comment: @PauloBu their position in the array is also irrelevant. The `data3` merged result in my question is _exactly_ what I want.

Comment: @PauloBu Where is `'id': 4` in your answer?

Comment: @MarkRichman just fixed. The solution lost its beauty with the last requirement. Probably following the other answer can lead you to a nicer solution.

Comment: @MarkRichman I improved the solution with the use of `groupby`. Can you take a look?

Answer (score 1):

A fairly straightforward procedural solution, where we build a dictionary keyed by item id, and then replace the items:

```
indexed_data = { item['id']: item for item in data1 }
# or, pre-Python2.7:
# indexed_data = dict((item['id'], item) for item in data1)
for item in data2:
    if indexed_data.get(item['id'], {'version': float('-inf')})['version'] < item['version']:
        indexed_data[item['id']] = item
data3 = [item for (_, item) in sorted(indexed_data.items())]
```

The same thing, but using a more functional approach:

```
sorted_items = sorted(data1 + data2, key=lambda item: (item['id'], item['version']))
merged = { item['id']: item for item in sorted_items }
# or, pre-Python2.7:
# merged = dict((item['id'], item) for item in sorted_items )
data3 = [item for (_, item) in sorted(merged.items())]
```

Comment: you probably want `{'version': float('-inf')}` to make sure you add the items not present in the first dict

Comment: For your second code block, you need to change the `sorted` in the `data3` comprehension.

Comment: In python 2.6.6 I am getting a syntax error on the first line. with the arrow pointing to the for. It does build the indexed_data using a multiline build of the dictionionary.

Comment: I changed the code to fix the bugs noted by njzk2 and Bill, and added comments to show how to make it work pre-Python2.7.